# Caused by: com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Expected EOF at line 1 column 21

Tags: java, rally, sample

I am trying to run the sample java program to retrieve the top 5 defects from rally. I am getting the following error:

```
Querying for top 5 highest priority unfixed defects...
Exception in thread "main" com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Expected EOF at line 1 column 21
    at com.google.gson.JsonParser.parse(JsonParser.java:65)
    at com.google.gson.JsonParser.parse(JsonParser.java:45)
    at com.rallydev.rest.response.Response.(Response.java:25)
    at com.rallydev.rest.response.QueryResponse.(QueryResponse.java:16)
    at com.rallydev.rest.RallyRestApi.query(RallyRestApi.java:179)
    at QueryExample.main(QueryExample.java:36)
Caused by: com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Expected EOF at line 1 column 21
    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.syntaxError(JsonReader.java:1298)
    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.peek(JsonReader.java:390)
    at com.google.gson.JsonParser.parse(JsonParser.java:60)
    ... 5 more
```

The source code is listed below:

```
import com.google.gson.JsonElement;
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
import com.rallydev.rest.RallyRestApi;
import com.rallydev.rest.request.QueryRequest;
import com.rallydev.rest.response.QueryResponse;
import com.rallydev.rest.util.Fetch;
import com.rallydev.rest.util.QueryFilter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;



public class QueryExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws URISyntaxException, IOException {

        //Create and configure a new instance of RallyRestApi
        RallyRestApi restApi = new RallyRestApi(new URI("https://rally1.rallydev.com/#/4608446320ud"), "stephen5@netapp.com", "password");
        restApi.setApplicationName("QueryExample");

        try {

            System.out.println("Querying for top 5 highest priority unfixed defects...");

            QueryRequest defects = new QueryRequest("defect");

            defects.setFetch(new Fetch("FormattedID", "Name", "State", "Priority"));
            defects.setQueryFilter(new QueryFilter("State", "<", "Fixed"));
            defects.setOrder("Priority ASC,FormattedID ASC");

            //Return up to 5, 1 per page
            defects.setPageSize(1);
            defects.setLimit(5);

            QueryResponse queryResponse = restApi.query(defects);
            if (queryResponse.wasSuccessful()) {
                System.out.println(String.format("\nTotal results: %d", queryResponse.getTotalResultCount()));
                System.out.println("Top 5:");
                for (JsonElement result : queryResponse.getResults()) {
                    JsonObject defect = result.getAsJsonObject();
                    System.out.println(String.format("\t%s - %s: Priority=%s, State=%s",
                    defect.get("FormattedID").getAsString(),
                    defect.get("Name").getAsString(),
                    defect.get("Priority").getAsString(),
                    defect.get("State").getAsString()));
                }
            } else {
                System.err.println("The following errors occurred: ");
                for (String err : queryResponse.getErrors()) {
                    System.err.println("\t" + err);
                }
            }

        } finally {
            //Release resources
            restApi.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Any help on what's causing this is greatly appreciated!

Comment: you need to post your JSON, after all: the exception tells us: Expected EOF at line 1 column 21

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code I think your URL:

`URI("https://rally1.rallydev.com/#/4608446320ud")`

is the problem, it needs to be just:

`URI("https://rally1.rallydev.com")`.

Rally REST URL's are of the form:

`https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/1.43/defect/12345678910.js`

so when the Java REST library is trying to formulate a query against the URL built from your code, it would end up looking like this:

`https://rally1.rallydev.com/#/4608446320ud/slm/webservice/1.43/defect/12345678910.js`

If you plug that into a browser you'll get a Rally 404, which contains a lot of HTML and formatting, not JSON. The "#/4608446320ud" string is used only in the RallyUI and provides project scoping information in the App. That UI-context explains why you would get a formatted HTML 404 response that the Java toolkit didn't know how to handle.